# SQL Query in SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Table Name - `Item`

I have a column called
`fruits` - apple;banana;mango;grapes

I have another column Called **Fruits collection** which is a `multiselect` - apple,mango,starwberry,pineapple (Input parameter)

My query is

```
select * from Item where fruits in (@FruitsCollection)
```

I am not getting any output. No rows are returned.

Comment: I suppose the typo's you made (`mango`, `strawberry`) are not the issue? Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?

Comment: No typos are not an issue. Sql server.

Comment: Not a lot of detail to go on there.  At least do a SELECT DISTINCT on the table and put eyes on the potential values next to your parameter values.  And as an obligatory question, any null values in that column?

Comment: The column name is fruits -- but it only ever has one fruit?  Why the plural?  And if it has a list (as the name suggests) then `in (@...)` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```
select * from Item where fruits = @FruitsCollection
```

In the parameter @FruitCollection make sure to select "allow multiple values"